# How to integrate shopify app in react native

Tags: react-native, shopify, shopify-app

I'm trying to build a shopify app using react native but i have a couple questions, How do i get all the products in my shopify and store them in an array and how do i get all the users/create and sign out users.

I tried to make a request to

```
https://{apikey}:{password}@{hostname}/admin/api/{version}/{resource}.json
```

but it gives error code401

Answer (score 0):

When you created private app then we can directly call api with below format like:

```
To get all products from shopify (by default shopify will return 50 products to get more products you need to go through [shopify curson based pagination][1])
https://{apikey}:{password}@{hostname}/admin/api/{version}/products.json
```

You can use [POSTMAN](https://www.getpostman.com/) to call api with your private app.

And if you want to get number of staff members(users) added/logged in in your store, to get [user api](https://help.shopify.com/en/api/reference/plus/user) you must have shopify plus store.